# Handle (“potentially” occuring) scalar-Vector and Vector-Vector operations

Tags: c++, performance, vectors

I'm looking into fixing some obvious performance-related issues in my code but I tend to employ bug-introducing tricks as I do so.

My code uses a library which defines `Field<scalar>` and `uniformField<scalar>`:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Field
{
    List<T> v_;
public:
    explicit Field(const Mesh&); // There are more args, but that's the important one
                             // v_ gets initialized based on mesh size.
    // operator[](int) is a proxy to List<T>::operator[](int)
};

template<class T>
class uniformField
{
    T v_;
public:
    uniformField(const Mesh&, const T&); // There are more args, but that's the important one
                             // v_ gets initialized to passed value.
    // operator[](int) is defined to always return v_ 
};
```

But I'm in a situation where, at run time, a specific variable can be either a single scalar
or a collection of scalars (collection size = mesh size).

> Currently, I'm replicating the single scalar to a full field, making use only of `Field` in both cases (The variable will always have mesh.nCells() elements which is a waste of memory and cpu; I expect 10000s to milions of these elements).

I thought of two options:

1. Make a new field class inheriting from both `Field` and `uniformField`. But this approach has obvious drawbacks:

- These classes are closely related and have no default constructors. Their constructors will probably be implicitly deleted in the derived one (if attempting to inherit them).
- The hope of using `operator[]` seamlessly perishes as I'll have to resolve the ambiguity of such operators manually.

2. Give up on using `uniformField` and use a single-element field for the scalar case.
   Now, that's easy, I just define:

```
class OneCellMesh : public Mesh; // Which will always have size = 1
                                 // and can be constructed from a Full Mesh object

// Initialize a scalar to erronous value (eg. if s is supposed to be positive:)
scalar s = -1;

// Consider user input
s = readScalar(); // If the user didn't specify this, "s" won't be touched.

// If didn't touch s, construct as a field
// else, construct as scalar
Field<scalar> sF( s == -1 ? fullMesh ! OneCellMesh(fullMesh));
```

The problem with this "volatile" construction is that it forces me to check the size
of `sF` every time if I want to write safe code. Particularly, `Field<T>` will generate UB code all over the place (Field::operator[] has no bound handling) and it's difficult to control the effects of such construction. Eg. what happens if one calls pow(Field&, Field&) where the parameters have different sizes?

Is there a better way to do this (in addition to building up my own class from scratch!)?

### For those of who want to see actual code

Consider `uniformField` to be [UniformDimensionedField from OpenFOAM](https://github.com/FoamScience/OpenFOAM-dev/blob/master/src/OpenFOAM/fields/UniformDimensionedFields/UniformDimensionedField.H#L54)
Consider `Field` to be [DimensionedField from OpenFOAM](https://github.com/FoamScience/OpenFOAM-dev/blob/master/src/OpenFOAM/fields/DimensionedFields/DimensionedField/DimensionedField.H#L71)

NB: In no way I'm suggesting review for those classes.

#### Working code (Current implementation):

```
    DimensionedField<scalar,volMesh> ss
    (
        IOobject
        (
            "ss",
            mesh.time().timeName(),
            mesh,
            IOobject::READ_IF_PRESENT,
            IOobject::AUTO_WRITE
        ),
        mesh, // Has many cells
        dimensionedScalar("ss", 0)
    );

    DimensionedField<scalar,volMesh> sv
    (
        IOobject
        (
            "ss",
            mesh.time().timeName(),
            mesh,
            IOobject::READ_IF_PRESENT,
            IOobject::AUTO_WRITE
        ),
        mesh, // Has many cells
        dimensionedScalar("sv", readScalar(dict))
    );

    // both sv and ss are of equal size, but as you can see,
    // sv is initialized from a user-provided scalar and won't be
    // changed any further.

    // Works but wasteful
    Info << sv + ss << endl;

    // Notice READ_IF_PRESENT
    // The user can write a file which is read into sv
    // Then, sv has many elements and the previous operation is not wasteful
```

I'm looking into optimizing `sv` so not to store many values but store a single scalar one and still benefit from a shared interface for both `sv` and `ss` types.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I've voted to close your question as [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We only review complete, functional code, that has sufficient review context for meaningful review. Right now the code does not seem to be fully written (and thus functional), and I don't feel like there is quite enough context to understand what problem you're trying to solve. Please feel free to [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/249219/edit) your question to include complete working code & more detailed explanation and we will happily review!

Comment: @Dannnno I explicitly mentioned how I'm doing things now "Currently, I'm replicating the single scalar to a full field, making use only of Field in both cases (The variable will always have mesh.nCells() elements which is a waste of memory and cpu; I expect 10000s to milions of these elements)."

Comment: Including complete code is not an option because of the huge dependency tree of the classes! I believe I included the relevant parts. I'm happy to clarify any issues of anyone has any!

Comment: @Dannnno I was the one who sent this user here, before he posted their question they confirmed their code **is** already working as intended, and they're looking for potential performance improvements. I agree, that the question could be improved by showing larger part of the code to see more context, but in no way there's a MCVE required at CR. So give them a chance, before close voting please.

Comment: @Dannnno I edited the question as you suggested. Hope it's in an acceptable state now

Comment: I do *not* find enough code presented in the [2nd revision](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/249219/2) to even guess where performance issues may arise, let alone be mended. (I'm not fond of having to search in the first place.)

Comment: (One idea coming to mind is to introduce `FieldExpression`s as 1st class citizen and build on lazy evaluation.)

Comment: @greybeard Already planning on Lazy Evaluation for next phase: Just need to absolutely make sure that the current code is bug-free :)

Comment: @greybeard the expression "ss+sv" may be wastefull if either vector is represented by a single scalar value. These vectors are expected to be big, so duplicating the scalar value to match the size of the vector is not "optimal" (Memory-wise and cpu-time-wise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Consider using `std::variant`

So what you want is something that can either hold a single value or a `std::vector` of values, with the idea that you don't want to pay for the memory and/or CPU overhead of a `std::vector` for a uniform field. Consider using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
template<typename T>
class Field {
    std::variant<T, std::vector<T>> v_;
public:
    explicit Field(const Mesh&); // initializes the vector
    uniformField(const Mesh&, const T&); // initializes the single value
};
```

And then all the member functions should check which variant is used. Of course, that will complicate all the member functions, and they do need to perform a runtime check. But you probably would have to pay that price somewhere anyway, if whether you want a regular field or uniform field depends on user input.

Alternatively:

## Make out-of-bounds handling fast

An advantage of your problem is that either you have a vector of arbitrary size, and code already is written such that they don't go out of bounds, or you want it to act like a vector but always return the same element. Consider storing a mask that is either all ones or all zeroes, depending on if it's a regular field or uniform field,
and use that to mask the index inside `operator[]`:

```
template<typename T>
class Field {
    std::vector<T> v_;
    size_t mask;
public:
    explicit Field(const Mesh&): mask{-1} {v_.reserve(/* mesh size */); ...}
    uniformField(const Mesh&, const T& value): mask{0}, v_{value} {...}

    T &operator[](size_t index) {
        return v_[index & mask];
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for the mask idea: already employing this for other things :) so It'll be consistent . I'm aware of "variant" but prefer not to use c++14. So, you say I'll have to check the mask (or the size) in operator+ .... and similar functions?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Check both masks in the operator overloads, and if they are different, then you know if you have the situation where you add a uniform field to a regular field or the other way around, and the result should then be a regular field.

Comment: Verified with experiment; The correct definition of operator[] is most enough as (most) other operators will use it. I think this is the way to go. Considering no further answers have been submitted in ~24 hours